# Is there a way to read an entire folder of files in R then export as 1 excel workbook with each files output as a sheet?

Tags: r, excel

I am mainly just having trouble with exporting the files as sheets and not individual excel files. The reason this is happening is because I have it in my for loop. How would I be able to write.xlsx all my files in the loop without looping the write.xlsx function itself?

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(mgsub)
library(openxlsx)

files <- list.files(path="\text files", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE) 

for(j in files){
  b <- readLines(j) 
  b <- mgsub(b, c('\t','for','hi'), c(',','food','hello')) 
  b <- data.frame(b) 
  b <- cSplit(b,1:ncol(b),sep = ',',stripWhite = TRUE, type.convert = FALSE) 
  b <- subset(b,select = -c(3,9))

  n <- dim(b)[1] 
  b <- b[1:(n-8),] 
  b[is.na(b)] <- '' 

  write.xlsx(b,file = "output files", append = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, have you tried using the same workbook name, different sheet names, and the `append = TRUE` argument?

Comment: I edited with code. @BigBen

Comment: I had this problem recently. You can pass a list of objects to the `write.xlsx` function and it will create separate sheets for each object in the list.

Comment: @Gregor I posted the code I believe its more of a problem with executing the write.xlsx inside the loop which will split it into individual workbooks instead. Right?

Comment: @luizgg Hmm so what would be the best way of going about this with my code? Should I try and assign the results to a variable and make that a list? Can I just pass a list of filenames to write.xlsx?

Comment: Your code (with `append=TRUE`) should work. I have similar code that is working.  Did you run it? What is not working?

Comment: @germany221 without changing much the code, I think in your `for` loop you would consolidate all the files in a list. I will write an answer.

Comment: @G5W I did it makes all different worksheets instead of one workbook with multiple sheets.

Comment: Following the comment of @Gregor try changing your write statement to `write.xlsx(b, file = "outputFiles.xlsx", append=TRUE, sheetName=j)`

Comment: @G5W haha it says the sheet names are too long because the files are the file paths. I can fix that I believe it will take me a little though.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were using `xlsx::write.xlsx`, which has a `sheet` argument.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think about specifying that my bad. @Gregor Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `write.xlsx` function from the `openxlsx`package, you can pass a list of objects to the function and it will create a sheet for each object in the list.

Something like this should work:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(mgsub)

files <- list.files(path="\text files", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE) 
result_list <- list()

for(j in 1:length(files)){
  b <- readLines(files[j]) 
  b <- mgsub(b, c('\t','for','hi'), c(',','food','hello')) 
  b <- data.frame(b) 
  b <- cSplit(b,1:ncol(b),sep = ',',stripWhite = TRUE, type.convert = FALSE) 
  b <- subset(b,select = -c(3,9))

  n <- dim(b)[1] 
  b <- b[1:(n-8),] 
  b[is.na(b)] <- '' 
  result_list[[j]] <- b
}

 write.xlsx(result_list, file = "output file")
```

Comment: Friendly edit to improve the loop. It will be faster to process the object separately, and then add it to the list when processing is complete. (Also simpler to read and less likely for typos.) And when you refer to a single list item, use `[[`, not `[`.